# Static variables initialization process

Tags: java, class, static-members

I have the following code:

```
public class StaticKindOfThing {
    static int a =getValue();
    static int b = 10;
    public static int getValue()
    {
        return b;
    }

    public static void main (String []args)
    {
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

I am aware that default variables are set to 0, however does not it happen at runtime? From the above code it appears that the default initialization to 0 happens before runtime.. otherwise getValue should give a compilation error or runtime exception not finding the value.
So my question is. Does the variable `static int b = 10;` get the 0 default value at compilation time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It gets value which you provide i.e, 10. Static variables are loaded at runtime

When you fire up a JVM and load the class StaticKindOfThing, then static blocks or fields(Here a, b) are 'loaded' into the JVM and become accessible.

From [here](http://www.javatutorialhub.com/java-static-variable-methods.html):-

> - It is a variable which belongs to the class and not to    object(instance)
> - Static variables are initialized only once , at the start of the    execution .
> - These variables will be initialized first, before the initialization    of any instance variables
> - A single copy to be shared by all instances of the class
> - A static variable can be accessed directly by the class name and    doesn’t need any object

**EDIT:-**

Please go through the [Detailed Initialization Procedure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/execution.html#12.4.2)

Comment: the output is 0 actually not 10

Comment: It is because you have not put the value of a in static block. try to put that in a static block and see the result.!!

Comment: Try this:- static int a; static{
    a = getValue();
}

Comment: I would like to know the exact moment in which the variable b get set to 0. It does get set to 0 as the result of my code is 0

Comment: when it gets set to 0.

Comment: When your class is loaded then it is set that is at the run time. I would recommend you to read this:- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html

Comment: before inlined initialization all the variables get set first at 0 right? otherwise does not make sense

Comment: I agree with your view +1

Comment: See the example given by Adriaan Koster to explain in this question:= http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343760/when-is-static-variable-loaded-in-java-runtime-or-compile-time

Comment: @Rollerball:- I have added the detailed initialization procedure doc on how the initialization takes place. Hope that helps for  you!!!!

Comment: I think that this 0 is set at compile time. as a final variable is. I will go through the detailed initial procedure however thanks

Answer (score 1):

No, it gets value you provided, aka 10.

In your case even you write:

```
static int a;
```

the result will be `0`. Because you didn't give any value.

Sometimes you can write `static` block like:

```
static {
  //...
}
```

to be sure that this block runs first before class initiation.

The static initializer block is executed only once when the class is loaded into the JVM like static variable.

Try this one that will do what you think:

```
public class StaticKindOfThing {

static int a;
static int b = 10;

static{
    a = getValue();
}


public static int getValue()
{
    return b;
}

public static void main (String []args)
 {
    System.out.println(a);
 }
}
```

Output: 10

Comment: I would like to know the exact moment in which the variable b get set to 0. It does get set to 0 as the result of my code is 0

Comment: When you run .class file, all static int variable without any provided value loaded into JVM with 0

Comment: the thing is that b has a provided value, is 10.

Comment: so why I get 0 instead of 10

Comment: @Rollerball:- Because your class is loaded and 'a' is the first static variable.

Comment: so it's safe to say that before the inilined initialization process all the variables present are first set to 0

Comment: yep, all primitives have initial values

Comment: here we are, and I think that those values are passed are embedded in the bytecode (compilation time) as it happens for a final variable.

Comment: because in "non initializing" code (in the main method for instance) primitive variables do need to be initialized